# rspec - how to change lambda should to expect?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have some lambda code, e.g.

```
lambda { Watir::Browser.new(mock_driver) }.should_not raise_error
```

How can I change this to use the expect syntax?

I tried:

```
expect({ Watir::Browser.new(mock_driver)}).to not raise_error
```

but I got:

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC (SyntaxError)
...expect ({Watir::Browser.new(mock_driver)}).to not raise_error
```

and I tried

```
expect{( Watir::Browser.new(mock_driver))}.to not raise_error
```

but got

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '('
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need those parentheses.

```
expect{Watir::Browser.new(mock_driver)}.to_not raise_error
```